# How can i play PC version servers on my raspberry pi

Tags: minecraft

I currently have the full version of Minecraft PC downloaded and working on my raspberry pi 2. The only problem is, that i can't connect to servers. The error it comes out with is invalid session id, try restarting your game.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Which version of Minecraft are you running ? My tutorial for Minecraft 1.12.1 includes the ability to connect to servers: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=186547

Comment: I am using 1.8.9 Minecraft. The link you gave is a newer version of minecraft made by the SAME guy. I will try out 1.12.1.

Comment: The same guy is me !

Comment: 0_0 cool! 1.12.1 works fine, but i have another question, is it safe to run my raspberry pi 3 overclocked at 1250MHZ. While running minecraft, the temperature get up to 75 degrees. Is this ok? i am using a home made super thin heatsink that doesn't help that much.

Comment: Yes, I overclock mine to 1300MHz. The Pi will throttle down the CPU at 80 degrees so Minecraft will slow down. I use a heatsink and fan when playing Minecraft.

Comment: Excellent, so I'm just 5 degrees off :D. Only problem with the the pi 3 is the wifi signal is rubbish, gonna have to use a dongle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My tutorial for Minecraft 1.12.1 includes the ability to connect to servers: http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=186547

Copied here for completeness:

**How to setup Full Minecraft 1.12.1 (with Optifine) on Raspberry Pi 3**

Please note : 
Do this at your own risk.
If you have any doubts use a spare SD card.
The OpenGL drivers are experimental - they may not work with all screens. If unsure make sure you can ssh onto the Pi from another machine to turn back off.
Most likely to have success with OpenGL drivers if using Raspberry Pi 3 with heatsink, genuine 5.1 volt 2.5 amp power supply with heavy duty 2 core power cable, 1080p screen.
This should also work on the Pi2.

This tutorial was tested using Raspbian Stretch with Desktop  - release date 2017-08-16

Video tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTRYomiQMAY

1 If you need to update an existing version use

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

If you get any questions or prompts during raspbian update press ‘q’ ‘enter’

2 In Menu\Preferences\Raspberry Pi Configuration :

System Tab - set Splash Screen to Disabled
Performance Tab - set GPU Memory to 64Mb
    - if using Pi2 set overclock to High(1000MHz) 
Reboot

3 Enable ‘GL Driver’ from a terminal window

```
sudo raspi-config
```

This will start the config utility. Select 'Advanced Options', then select 'GL Driver', then select 'Enable' (latest utility requires selection of 'GL (Full KMS)' ), then select 'Yes' to reboot and enable the driver.

4 Install OpenAL Audio & glxgears demo

```
sudo apt-get -y install libalut0 libalut-dev && sudo apt-get -y install mesa-utils
```

5 Test driver using glxgears

```
glxgears
```

This should run at about 60 fps.

6 Download Minecraft

```
mkdir ~/Minecraft; mkdir ~/Minecraft/Natives; cd ~/Minecraft && wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar
```

7 Run launcher :

```
cd ~/Minecraft && java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Login with Minecraft email and password
If your using a newer Minecraft.jar click 'edit profile' and select use release - 'release 1.12.1', then 'save profile'
Click Play to install game
You will then receive an error
Close launcher

8 Copy libraries

```
cd ~/Minecraft/Natives && wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/4oxcvz3ky7a3x6f/liblwjgl.so && wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0r8e01jg2og36z/libopenal.so
```

9 Update lwjgl

```
cd ~/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.4-nightly-20150209 && rm lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar; wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj15sz3bub4dmr6/lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar
```

( based on Roger Allen's tutorial : http://rogerallen.github.io/jetson/2014/07/31/minecraft-on-jetson-tk1/ )

10 Download “OptiFine 1.12.1 HD U C5” from http://optifine.net/downloads

11 Install Optifine

```
cd ~/Downloads && java -jar OptiFine_1.12.1_HD_U_C5.jar
```

Click install.

Run launcher

```
cd ~/Minecraft && java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Select the OptiFine profile and click play. The launcher will crash

12 Copy run script

```
cd ~/Minecraft/ && wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/ca37tzxxc9hvsyd/runOptifine1_12_1.sh && sudo chmod +x runOptifine1_12_1.sh
```

13 Edit runOptifine1_12_1.sh

Update MINECRAFT_LOGIN, MINECRAFT_USERNAME and MINECRAFT_PASSWORD to your own (may need "" for special characters)

14 Start Minecraft from terminal window

```
./runOptifine1_12_1.sh
```

Change options in Minecraft to reduce render chunks to 2, this should avoid running out of memory.
Turn everything down to low in the video settings (and turn on things like fast math)
Suggest running in the default sized window for best performance - full screen may crash.

https://youtu.be/2sREfySmRNU

Hopefully Minecraft should run :)